# QGIS label expression to print "key:value" from a list of dictionaries (coming from an http vector source) in the print layout

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression, json

### Context

In a [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/) 3.16 project, I have a vector data source defined as a connection to a [REST](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) ([Python](https://www.python.org/) backend):

[image: REST API vector data source]

From the `/authors` endpoint of the API, I fetch this nested [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) object:

```
'[{ "id": 1 ,
    "first_name": "John" ,
    "last_name": "Taylor" ,
    "company_name": "ABC" ,
    "address": " Long Street 2" ,
    "zipcode": 226131 ,
    "city": "Bigcity" ,
    "phone": "77 66 55 44 33 22" ,
    "email": "john.taylor@email.org" ,
    "type": "Admin" },
  { "id": 2 ,
    "first_name": "James" ,
    "last_name": "Chester" ,
    "company_name": "ZXY" ,
    "address": "Short Avenue 10" ,
    "zipcode": 226132 ,
    "city": "Smallcity" ,
    "phone": "22 33 44 55 66 77" ,
    "email": "james.chester@email.org" ,
    "type": "Customer" } ]'
```

For a better comprehension, in the API backend I'm connecting to, the `author` object is a Python [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) of [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), each dictionary storing all the characteristics belonging to an author as "key:value" pairs, such as his name, phone, address, etc.

I wish I could display a paragraph as a label on my atlas, using each of the `key` elements of the dictionaries followed by a colon and then their corresponding `value`, as such:

> id: 1
> first_name: John
> last_name: Taylor
> ...
> type: Admin
>
> id: 2
> first_name: James
> last_name: Chester
> ...
> type: Customer

In order to to that, I inserted a text label in my print layout for which I'm trying to use an expression:

[image: print composer text expression menu]

### Using a native QGIS expression

I actually have something like this (which is not working):

```
array_foreach(
  from_json("author"),
    array_foreach(
      map_akeys(@element) || ': ' map_get(@element2) # <-- how to differentiate this level-2 element here?
    )
)
```

And for which I'm facing an issue when trying to extract the `key:values` information from the embedded dictionaries using two nested `array_foreach()` loops.
The first one is needed to loop over the elements of the list, i.e. all the dictionaries. And the second one to loop over the "key:value" pairs *inside* each dictionary, which I'd like to extract and display on my print layout.
The problem is that I cannot differentiate this `@element` object when it's used in the children `array_foreach()` loop from the one in the parent loop... And from the doc, this `@element` is used to represent the current value we are looping onto:

> The variable `@element` will be replaced by the current value.

This is the help on [`array_foreach()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-foreach) as shown in the QGIS expression composer:

[image: help on array_foreach() in the QGIS expression composer]

A small parenthesis here; if I don't use `from_json()` on the incoming array of authors, QGIS throws me this error, which I don't clearly understand, because the object I'm dealing with *should* be an array :

```
Eval Error: Cannot convert '[{ "id": 1, "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Taylor", "company_name": "ABC", "address": " Long Street 2", "zipcode": 226131, "city": "Bigcity", "phone": "77 66 55 44 33 22", "email": "john.taylor@email.org", "type": "Admin" },
  { "id": 2, "first_name": "James", "last_name": "Chester", "company_name": "ZXY", "address": "Short Avenue 10", "zipcode": 226132, "city": "Smallcity", "phone": "22 33 44 55 66 77", "email": "james.chester@email.org", "type": "Customer" } ]'     
to array
```

But this is not a big deal as using `from_json()` solved it.

### Using a python function as an expression

I also build a Python function, which is perfectly working, *but* I cannot embed this function into my `*.qgs` project file! The function itself is stored separately in a `*.py` file, making the project impossible to easily share.

### Question

How can I get the desired formatted output in my layout, as shown above, based on the JSON object given as input that is composed of a list of dictionaries?

1. using a QGIS native expression, or
2. by embedding a Python function in my QGIS project file
   ?

Comment: It seems to be a string (which is technically a list, but not what your want). If you pass it through `json.loads()`, it would become an array.

Comment: Yes, this is what the `from_json` function from the available functions in the QGIS expression builder seems to actually do, it sounds it's equivalent to your `json.loads()` (but there is no such `json.loads()` function) inside the QGIS expression builder. But that's really a minor detail.

Comment: I revised my answer to consider varying length of the input array/map (containing changing number of elements). I hope this works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate the following output, based on your JSON object, use the expression from below (see at the bottom under **Expression** - the second expression contains comments to show how it works). At the beginning, the variable `@input` is created that takes your JSON object. This allows to use this twice in a simple way, also together with a `array_length()` function to dynamically adapt it automatically to inputs with changing numbers of elements (maps) contained in it. Alternative would be to define a custom variable (see below as well).

[image]

## Options

**Convert dynamic expression to static output**

By the way: since QGIS 3.20, once the expression generates the output you want, you can simply [convert the dynamic, or expression-based labels to static text](https://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-convert-to-static-text-option) - that allows you to "manually tweak the results when needed." This is especially useful if formatted as html (see next paragraph).

[image]

**Style as html**

Another option would be styling using html - the necessary styling html-tags could be included in the expression. You could replace e.g. `array_get (map_akeys( @map),@element)` with `'<b>'  || array_get (map_akeys( @map),@element)  || '</b>'` to get the key-description formatted as bold (see below for the whole expression):

[image]

**Create a custom variable for the JSON object**

As you see in both expressions, I added your JSON object as a variable to the expression. You could also create a custom variable to define the JSON object there and thus make the expression a bit more straightforward, see:
[image]

*With custom variable and html-formatting, using the second expression from below:*

[image]

## Expression

**Expression for normally formatted output**

Here is the expression used to generate the output from the first screenshot:

```
with_variable (
    'input',
    '('' [{ "id": 1, "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Taylor", "company_name": "ABC", "address": " Long Street 2", "zipcode": 226131,"city": "Bigcity", "phone": "77 66 55 44 33 22","email": "john.taylor@email.org", "type": "Admin" },
    {"id": 2, "first_name": "James", "last_name": "Chester", "company_name": "ZXY", "address": "Short Avenue 10", "zipcode": 226132,"city": "Smallcity", "phone": "22 33 44 55 66 77", "email": "james.chester@email.org", "type": "Customer" },
    {"id": 3, "first_name": "Larry", "last_name": "Smith", "company_name": "DEF", "address": " Bright Street 77", "zipcode": 613122,"city": "Tinycity", "phone": "44 33 22 77 66 55 ", "email": "larry.smith@mail.org", "type": "Staff" },
    {"id": 4, "first_name": "Peter", "last_name": "Webber", "company_name": "UVW", "address": "Beatiful Boulevard 88", "zipcode": 872046,"city": "Nicecity", "phone": "66 77 22 33 44 55 ", "email": "peter.webber@nice.web", "type": "Contact" }]''
                     )',
    replace (
        wordwrap (
            replace (
                array_to_string (
                    array_foreach (
                        generate_series (0,array_length (from_json(eval(@input)))),
                        with_variable (
                            'map',
                            array_get (from_json(eval(@input)),@element),
                            array_to_string (
                                array_foreach (
                                    array(5,4,6,2,0,9,1,7,3,8),
                                    array_get (
                                        array_foreach (
                                            generate_series (0,9),
                                            array_get (map_akeys( @map),@element)  || 
                                            ': ' || 
                                            array_get (map_avals( @map),@element)
                                        ),
                                        @element                            
                )))))),
                'id: ',
                ',id: '
            ), 
            1, 
            ','
        ),
        ',',
        ''
))
```

**Expression for output formatted as html**

And here is the corresponding expression to create a html-formatted style as in the last screenshot, but this time the variable `@input` is not part of the expression, but defined as custom variable. Instead, comments are inserted to document how the expression works:

```
substr(   --line 1: replace the first 4 characters to eliminate the html-line-brake tag <br>, see line 23
    replace (  --line 2: remove the commas generated when the array is converted to text in line 9; see line 21
        array_to_string (   --line 3
            array_foreach (    --line 4: for each element in the list of the JSON object iterate through the following expression
                generate_series (0,array_length (from_json(eval(@input)))),  --line 5: the variable @input is set as context variable, it represents the JOSN object; here it is used to generate a series for each element (entry) in the list of the JSON object
                with_variable ( --line 6: define a variable @map 
                    'map', --line 7: name the variable
                    array_get (from_json(eval(@input)),@element), --line 8: set the value of the variable: it evaluates the @input variable (JSON object), creates an array of it and and from this array the the element N, where N is iterated with the array_foreach function from lines 4/5: so here we get for each iteration one element (author) of the input JSON object
                    array_to_string ( --line 9
                        array_prepend(  --line 10: add another element at the end of the array: a html inebreak tag <br> in line 19: only at the end of each author
                            array_foreach ( --line 11: iterate through each key:value-pair of each element (author) (cf. line 12 and 17)
                                array(5,4,6,2,0,9,1,7,3,8), --line 12: the sort-order of the elements, as the array sorts alphabetically, but we want a custom defined order that is done here with the index of the (alphabetically sorted) array
                                    array_get ( --line 13: now get the N-th element of the array (line 17, defined as @element, refering to the array in line 12
                                        array_foreach ( --line 14 repeat the following steps for each item (key:value pair) of every author
                                            generate_series (0,9), --line 15: as we have 10 attributes for each author, we make a series of 10 integers (starting from 0)
                                            '<b>'  ||  array_get (map_akeys( @map),@element)  || '</b>' || ': ' || array_get (map_avals( @map),@element) || '<br>'),  --line 16: here finally we concatenate different elements like html-tags (for formatting and line-breaks), string/punctuation-elements line colon (:) and getting the string-represenation of each key:value pair: @element refers to the current value of line 15 for each iteration
                                        @element   -- line 17: this time, @element refers to the current value of line 12 for the iteration as we are inside this function here
                            )), -- line 18
                            '<br>'  --line 19 (see comment for line 10)
        )))))  --line 20
        ,',','' -- line 21: arguments from the replace-function in line 2: remove the commas by an empty string (delete commas)
    ), --line 22
    5   --line 23: returns the substring starting from postion 5, thereby cutting the first 4 characters: <br> - what would result in a linebreak before the firs item
) -- line 24
```